# What is overriding my @media queries preventing the breakpoints from applying?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Very first post, please forgive me and advise me on what is incorrect in regards to posting here, and thank you very much.

Trying to make simple site from example for Coursera course "`HTML, CSS, and Javascript` for Web Developers." I will post the objectives and image that have been given first, then my `html/css`, and then the second version which is a complete mess (please advise how to do this better in future posts if needed. No `Bootstrap` or any other `frameworks` are permitted in this project.

Attempting to make page `fully responsive` as it is shrunk down, instead of just using specific pixel sizes for each media size.  Ignore the other most-likely errors in font-sizes etc (unless you feel like giving me advice on everything I'm doing wrong, which I would welcome).  The focus is getting the "row" of three-wide containers 100% width to drop down to two rows with 2 `containers` 100% width in first row, and 1 container 100% width in second row.  Then scale down again to three rows with 1 container 100% wide in each. All of this is in better detail in the project objectives linked below.

The other issue I'm having is excess space on right side after last container in the current version when I can't find what is causing it as I have margins set to 0 and width of container set to 100%.

I have tried creating a `css grid` by specifying different col classes and a base width for them all, then having the `@media` change these with no change.

**PROJECT INSTRUCTIONS** (found at https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/blob/master/assignments/assignment2/Assignment-2.md)

[Example Page To Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5GLt.png)

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment Solution for Module 2</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Roboto|Sansita" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div id="container">
<!-- Chicken Container -->
    <div id="op-1" class="menu">
        <div class="food-type chicken">Chicken
        </div>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>

<!-- Beef Container -->
    <div id="op-2" class="menu">
        <div class="food-type beef">Beef
        </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>


<!-- Sushi Container -->
    <div id="op-3" class="menu">
        <div class="food-type sushi">Sushi
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*===============================================
 My CSS Styles
 =============================================== */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: raleway; roboto; ransita; sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0;
}


h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
     /*display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; */
}

.menu {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;
}
/*
div.foo {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;
}
*/

div.food-type {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    /*left: 70%;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

div.chicken {
    background: pink;
}

div.beef {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

div.sushi {
    background: yellow;
}

p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .75em;
    clear: right;
}

@media all (min-width: 992px) {
     .menu {width: 33.33%;}
}

@media all (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #op-1.menu #op-2.menu {width: 50%;}
    #id-3.menu {width: 100%;}
}

@media all (max-width: 767px) {
     .menu {width: 100%;}
}
```

Version 2 Attempt with CSS Grid-
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment Solution for Module 2</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Roboto|Sansita" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles2.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<div id="grid-container">
<!-- Chicken Container -->
<div id="op-1" class="menu col-2 col-3 col-6">
  <div class="food-type chicken">
  Chicken
  </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
</div>

<!-- Beef Container -->
<div id="op-2" class="menu col-2 col-3 col-6">
    <div class="food-type beef">
Beef
    </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
</div>

<!-- Sushi Container -->
<div id="op-3" class="menu op-3 col-2 col-3 col-6">
<div class="food-type sushi">
Sushi
</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*===============================================
 My CSS Styles
 =============================================== */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: raleway; roboto; ransita; sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0;
}


h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}



.menu {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;
}  

div.food-type {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    /*left: 70%;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

div.chicken {
    background: pink;
}

div.beef {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

div.sushi {
    background: yellow;
}

p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .75em;
    clear: right;
}

.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
}

 /*
    .row:before, 
    .row:after {
        content:"";
          display: table ;
        clear:both;
    }
*/


    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left; 
        min-height: 1px; 
        width: 33.33%; 
        padding: 12px;
    }

/*
    .col-1{ width: 16.66%; } 
    .col-2{ width: 33.33%; }
    .col-3{ width: 50%;    }
    .col-4{ width: 66.66%; }
    .col-5{ width: 83.33%; }
    .col-6{ width: 100%;   }  */

@media all (min-width: 992px) {
     .col-2 {width: 33.33%;}
}

@media all (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #id-1 #id-2 .col-3 {width: 50%;}
    #id-3 .col-6 {width: 100%;}
}

@media all (max-width: 767px) {
     #id-1 #id-2 #id-3 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Thank you very much, sorry for so many words, again please let me know how to improve for future posts.

Comment: Try to check in chrome inspector. You'll clearly see which rule is overriding your media query.

Comment: I'm still very new to chrome inspector, however I have inspected everything and can see which things are applied and which are overridden, I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your media queries: is missing the word 'and' between the rules and the comma (,) between selectors #op-1.menu and $op-2.menu in the second media query.

Here is the media queries corrected

```
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
    .menu {width: 30%;}
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #op-1.menu, #op-2.menu {width: 47%;}
    #op-3.menu {width: 100%;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: I added the correct syntax with the word "all" (thanks for pointing that out!) However I did not see a comma in my code as mentioned.
The page is responsive now going from 3 containers wide down to all three stacked... but I'm still missing the medium screen version with two containers spanning the first row and the last container on second row at 100% width.

Comment: You need to apply a same css rule to two elements, in this case you need separate those elements (selectors) with a comma (#op-1.menu, #op-2.menu )

Comment: Huge improvement! It is now making the correct breakpoints, thank you! The medium sized version is having the bottom div width 100% span entire width with no margin like the top two, which is odd because I have the extra space on right of top two that I can't get rid of but bottom one does not have it.  However, my original issue of media query not functioning properly has been solved with the changes provided, so I will try to figure that out on my own before pulling from all of you again.  Many thanks, this forum is amazing and lifechanging.

Answer (score 0):

If you use media queries with `min-width` the order is from small to higher width in css, otherwise if counting on `max-width` you have to go from large to small screens.

**Solution:** Whenever you use media queries, take a good care of the order in css so it cascades and not overwrite yourself. Switch the order of media queries so it goes from small to large screens when you use `min-width` as parameter.

Comment: Is it not written in that order? 

  media all (min-width: 992px) {
  .menu {width: 33.33%;}
}

media all (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 #op-1.menu #op-2.menu {width: 50%;}
 #id-3.menu {width: 100%;}
}

media all (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu {width: 100%;}
}

Answer (score 0):

you have define @media queries like as this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 992px) { ... }
```

the 'and' keyword is missing after `@media all`

There are some points there, for example to find actual width based on 10px margin in left/right side of each menu box. e.g when all 3 box shall be visible in large screen sizes, we can set width as:

```
width: calc( (100% - 60px) / 3 ); /* 60px is 3*20, ( 20px = 10+10 Left+Right Margins) */
```

I modified your code as the following:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: raleway, roboto, ransita, sans-serif; /* **change ; to , */
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
     /*display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; */
}

.menu {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;

    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}

/*
div.foo {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;
}
*/

div.food-type {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%; /* *** */
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: right;
    /*left: 70%;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

div.chicken {
    background: pink;
}

div.beef {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

div.sushi {
    background: yellow;
}

p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .75em;
    clear: right;
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) { /* width > 992px */
      .menu {width: calc( (100% - 60px) / 3 ); } /* 31% */
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { /* 768px < width < 991px  */
    #op-1.menu {width: calc( (100% - 40px) / 2 );} /* 47% */
    #op-2.menu {width: calc( (100% - 40px) / 2 );}
    #op-3.menu {width: calc(100% - 20px);}
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) { /* width < 768px  */
      .menu {width: calc(100% - 20px);}
}
```

```html
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <!-- Chicken Container -->
    <div id="op-1" class="menu">
      <div class="food-type chicken">
        Chicken
      </div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Beef Container -->
    <div id="op-2" class="menu">
      <div class="food-type beef">
        Beef
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>


    <!-- Sushi Container -->
    <div id="op-3" class="menu">
      <div class="food-type sushi">
        Sushi
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I have the div.food-type width set to 30% to make the box with food title 1/3 the size of the container it is living in that contains the paragraph

Comment: in my code, the margins are taken into account to have similar exact spacing!

Comment: Thanks for showing me a new method! I have no idea the logic behind it yet as I'm just testing it, but definitely going to learn about it.  It DID fix the extra space on the right, but now the large version doesn't fit all three. I'm assuming they are just a bit over the total width limit, should I play with the math formula to try to decrease their widths so they fit?

Comment: i tested it and it works in wide screen size, all 3 columns are beside each other, but it may something in your html code or browser... can you test `calc( (100% - 60px) / 3 - 2px);` for first @media?

Comment: That caused them to all stack as they do in the smallest version.  I've been playing with different values in the first @media formula but can't seem to make a difference. calc( (100% - 600px) / 3 ); didn't even effect it. (I just threw out a huge number to see if anything changed.  This leads me to believe I have something wrong as you said with my HTML or other part of the code.

Comment: When I viewed it in Safari, the large view never unstacked at all, whereas in Chrome it at least has the two boxes on top row with large gap on right where last that moved down to next row one should be.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your test to see and test your code compeletly?

Comment: (I tried moving this to chat but I'm still too new w/o enough points)
Same result in fiddle as before.  I have found that by changing it to cal ( (100% - 60px) / **3.2** ); gets the entire 3 on one row (there is extra space on the right however. I played with ranges from 3.10 - 3.19 and they would get them all in-line but then overflow to second row before breakpoint as it was shrunk down.  Should I make a new post regarding this now?

Comment: Found the issue, I was missing the space on **both** sides of the ( - ) operator inside (100% - 60px) / 3 ).  Many thanks to everyone for helping me through this and teaching me how important such minor things can be.

Comment: I have upvoted and it was recorded but not applied due to my lack of rep points being new.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single one of your media queries is syntactically correct.

> ```
> @media all (min-width: 992px) {
> ```

It needs to be

```
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my another answer, adding a parent div for menu box items and use its `padding` instead of the `margin` for inner menu box. The main advantage of this method is that all sizes (33.33%, 50%, 100%) could be set to exact values we need (see `@media` widths) without using special estimated values or calc formulas or javascript ...

```css
body {
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: raleway, roboto, ransita, sans-serif; /* **change ; to , */
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* apply it to main container */
}

.menu { /* menu external box */
  float: left;
  padding: 10px; /* instead of inner menu margin */
  width: 33.33%; /* just a default width for case we are at large screens */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* apply it to main container */
}

.menu > div { /* menu internal box (menu-child) */
    /*float:left;*/ /* EDIT! moved to parent div */
    width:100%; /* EDIT! fill whole of parent, the size is set by parent */
    /*margin: 10px;*/ /* EDIT! set by padding of parent div */
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-size: .75em;
}


div.food-type {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 5px; /* padding-left & right could be less as we center title text */
    width: 40%; /* or width: auto; min-width: 33%; to ensure large titles not overflow the width size */
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

div.chicken {
    background: pink;
}

div.beef {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

div.sushi {
    background: yellow;
}

p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .75em;
    clear: right;
}


@media all and (min-width: 992px) { /* width > 992px */
  .menu { width:33.33%; padding:10px; float:left;}
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { /* 768px < width < 991px  */
  #op-1.menu {width: 50%;}
  #op-2.menu {width: 50%;}
  #op-3.menu {width: 100%;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) { /* width < 768px  */
  .menu {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <!-- Chicken Container -->

    <div id="op-1" class="menu">
      <div> <!-- class="menu-child" -->
        <div class="food-type chicken">
          Chicken
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Beef Container -->
    <div id="op-2" class="menu">
      <div> <!-- class="menu-child" -->
        <div class="food-type beef">
          Beef
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Sushi Container -->
    <div id="op-3" class="menu">
      <div> <!-- class="menu-child" -->
        <div class="food-type sushi">
          Sushi
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please check this new answer, and give your feedback